# I am trying to extract some data from espn as a table and getting it as list

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

start_urls = http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/18679/scorecard/1144998/australia-vs-india-2nd-odi-india-in-aus-2018-19

I scraped this site and extracted the match result(winning team) and then I yielded the player URL and I want to print the player name and the batting style. My first problem is 
1. I cant abstract the player batting sytle. it is under `<pclass="ciPlayerinformationtxt"><b>Batting style</b> <span>Right-hand bat</span>`. I was only able to extract the text 'Batting style'.How to extract 'Right-hand bat'
2.I was unable to yield the whole extracted data as a table. The result I got was like

p
link of all the player
http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/326434.html

Player_name Country 
Alex Carey  Australia
Kuldeep Yadav   India
Mohammed Siraj  India
Winning_Team:India

```
class ScoreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'score'
    allowed_domains = ['espncricinfo.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        Player_URLs=[]

        #got the result

        result= response.xpath('//div[@class="cscore_notes"]/span/text()').extract_first()
        result=result.split(" ")
        Winning_Team =result[0]

        #extracted player ulrs

        Batting_Player_URLs=response.xpath('//div[@class="cell batsmen"]/a/@href').extract()
        Bowling_Player_URLs=response.xpath('//*[@class="scorecard-section bowling"]/table/tbody/tr/td/a/@href').extract()

        #added to a list

        Player_URLs.extend(Batting_Player_URLs)
        Player_URLs.extend(Bowling_Player_URLs)
        for p in Player_URLs:
            yield Request(p,callback=self.parse_players,meta={'p':p})
            yield{'Winning_Team':Winning_Team}

    def parse_players(self,response):
        Player_name=response.xpath('//div[@class="ciPlayernametxt"]/div/h1/text()').extract_first()
        Country=response.xpath('//div[@class="ciPlayernametxt"]/div/h3/b/text()').extract_first()

        #this wont give the batting style but the 'batting style' as text
        Batting_style=response.xpath('//div[@class="ciPlayerinformationtxt"]/p/text()').extract_first()

        yield{'Player_name':Player_name,
              'Country':Country, 
              'Batting_style':Batting_style}
```

what I want is the extracted data as a single table and I wanted to avoid repetition.

```
          yield{'Winning_Team':Winning_Team,
                'Player_name':Player_name,
                'Country':Country,
                'Batting_style':Batting_style}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust your XPath:

```
batting_style = response.xpath('//p[@class="ciPlayerinformationtxt"]/b[.="Batting style"]/following-sibling::span[1]/text()').get()
```

**UPDATE**

```
for p in Player_URLs:
    yield Request(p,callback=self.parse_players,meta={'Winning_Team':Winning_Team})
```

and later:

```
def parse_players(self,response):
    Winning_Team = response.meta["Winning_Team"]
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps me with the first question. Can help me to yield all the datas at once?

Comment: You need to use `request.meta` to send `Winning_Team` from `parse` to `parse_players`

Comment: Thank you very much. But the data is printing as a list. How can I print it as a table?Like Winning_Team, Player_name, Country, Batting_style as respective headers and the yielded data in those columns?